Python Question How to create spot colors that register as cutlines in PDF?
I am working on a project that requires me to create a cutline around an image and am having difficulties with it registering as an actual cut line on any of the RIP programs such as Versaworks or Flexi.
I have tried a bunch of different python libraries to help with this but am unable to get this to work. I would like it to create a cutline as a spotcolor with the name CutContour like what we do in Illustrator, but for some reason it is not registering on export.
I have tried pillow, element tree, inkscape, scribus to no effect.
import subprocess
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def convert_png_to_svg(input_image_path, output_svg_path):
    try:
        subprocess.run(['C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\bin\\inkscape.exe', input_image_path, '--export-type=svg', '--export-filename', output_svg_path], check=True)
        if os.path.exists(output_svg_path):
            print(f"SVG file created: {os.path.abspath(output_svg_path)}")
        else:
            print(f"Error: SVG file was not created: {output_svg_path}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error running Inkscape: {e}")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Inkscape not found. Make sure it's installed at the specified path.")

def remove_small_objects(mask, min_size):
    num_labels, labels, stats, _ = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(mask, connectivity=8)
    for i in range(1, num_labels):
        if stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA] < min_size:
            mask[labels == i] = 0
    return mask

def add_contour_to_svg(input_image_path, svg_path, output_svg_path, border_size, padding):
    # Open the original image
    img = Image.open(input_image_path).convert("RGBA")

    # Add initial padding to the original image
    padded_size = (img.width + 2 * padding, img.height + 2 * padding)
    padded_img = Image.new("RGBA", padded_size, (0, 0, 0, 0))
    padded_img.paste(img, (padding, padding))

    # Convert to numpy array
    img_np = np.array(padded_img)

    # Create an alpha mask
    alpha = img_np[:, :, 3]

    # Create a binary mask
    mask = (alpha > 0).astype(np.uint8) * 255

    # Remove small objects (smaller than 1px)
    mask = remove_small_objects(mask, 1)

    # Find contours using OpenCV
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Find the outer contour
    outer_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # Create a new mask for the border
    border_mask = np.zeros_like(mask)

    # Draw the contour on the border mask with a thicker stroke
    cv2.drawContours(border_mask, [outer_contour], -1, 255, border_size)

    # Find the contours of the border mask
    border_contours, _ = cv2.findContours(border_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    border_contour = max(border_contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # Parse the SVG
    tree = ET.parse(svg_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    ns = {'svg': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'}

    # Create a new layer for the cut path
    layer = ET.SubElement(root, 'g', {
        'id': 'cut_layer',
        'inkscape:groupmode': 'layer',
        'inkscape:label': 'CutContour'
    })

    # Create the cut path
    path_data = 'M ' + ' '.join(f'{px},{py}' for px, py in [point[0] for point in border_contour]) + ' Z'
    ET.SubElement(layer, 'path', {
        'd': path_data,
        'fill': 'none',
        'stroke': '#EC008C',
        'stroke-width': str(border_size)
    })

    # Save the modified SVG
    tree.write(output_svg_path)
    print(f"Modified SVG with contour saved as: {output_svg_path}")

def export_svg_to_pdf(svg_path, output_pdf_path):
    try:
        subprocess.run(['C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\bin\\inkscape.exe', svg_path, '--export-type=pdf', '--export-filename', output_pdf_path], check=True)
        if os.path.exists(output_pdf_path):
            print(f"PDF file created: {os.path.abspath(output_pdf_path)}")
        else:
            print(f"Error: PDF file was not created: {output_pdf_path}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error running Inkscape: {e}")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Inkscape not found. Make sure it's installed at the specified path.")

# Input image path
input_image_path = '2.png'
# Output SVG paths
output_svg_path = '2_converted.svg'
modified_svg_path = '2_with_cut.svg'
# Output PDF path
output_pdf_path = '2_final.pdf'
# Border size (pixels)
border_size = 1
# Padding size (pixels)
padding = 10

# Step 1: Convert PNG to SVG using Inkscape
convert_png_to_svg(input_image_path, output_svg_path)

# Step 2: Add cut path and spot color to the SVG
add_contour_to_svg(input_image_path, output_svg_path, modified_svg_path, border_size, padding)

# Step 3: Export the modified SVG to PDF using Inkscape
export_svg_to_pdf(modified_svg_path, output_pdf_path)


I fixed it - solution code adds border and cutline to any png named 2.png in project directory. Solution above

This code will add a padding border and cutline to any file that registers in both Flexi and Versaworks. For now you need to have a file named 2.png in your project directory but you can easily build on this.
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
import cv2
import os
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.colors import PCMYKColorSep
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader


def remove_small_objects(mask, min_size):
    num_labels, labels, stats, _ = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(mask, connectivity=8)
    for i in range(1, num_labels):
        if stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA] < min_size:
            mask[labels == i] = 0
    return mask


def create_image_with_border(input_image_path, border_size, corner_radius):
    # Open the original image
    img = Image.open(input_image_path).convert("RGBA")

    # Convert to numpy array
    img_np = np.array(img)

    # Remove pixels with opacity lower than 60%
    img_np[img_np[:, :, 3] < 153] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

    # Create an alpha mask
    alpha = img_np[:, :, 3]

    # Create a binary mask
    mask = (alpha > 0).astype(np.uint8) * 255

    # Remove small objects (smaller than 2px)
    mask = remove_small_objects(mask, 2)

    # Convert mask to PIL Image
    mask_img = Image.fromarray(mask)

    # Calculate new size with padding
    padding = max(border_size * 3, corner_radius * 2)
    new_size = (img_np.shape[1] + padding * 2, img_np.shape[0] + padding * 2)

    # Create a new image with extra space for the border
    img_with_border = Image.new('RGBA', new_size, (0, 0, 0, 0))

    # Create a mask for the contour
    contour_mask = Image.new('L', new_size, 0)
    paste_position = (padding, padding)
    contour_mask.paste(mask_img, paste_position)

    # Apply corner rounding
    contour_mask = contour_mask.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=corner_radius / 2))
    contour_mask = contour_mask.point(lambda x: 255 if x > 128 else 0)

    # Create the contour border
    contour_border = contour_mask.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=border_size / 2))
    contour_border = contour_border.point(lambda x: 255 if x > 0 else 0)

    # Create a white layer for the border
    white_layer = Image.new('RGBA', new_size, (255, 255, 255, 255))

    # Paste the white border behind the image
    img_with_border.paste(white_layer, (0, 0), contour_border)

    # Paste the original image on top
    img_with_border.paste(Image.fromarray(img_np), paste_position, Image.fromarray(mask))

    return img_with_border


def create_contour(image):
    # Convert image to numpy array
    img_np = np.array(image)

    # Create a binary mask
    mask = (img_np[:, :, 3] > 0).astype(np.uint8) * 255

    # Find contours
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Find the outer contour
    outer_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

    return outer_contour


def create_pdf_with_spot_color(image, contour, pdf_path, cutline_offset):
    # Get image dimensions
    img_width, img_height = image.size

    # Create a new PDF canvas
    c = canvas.Canvas(pdf_path, pagesize=(img_width + 2 * cutline_offset, img_height + 2 * cutline_offset))

    # Define the spot color for the cut contour
    cut_contour_spot = PCMYKColorSep(0.0, 100.0, 91.0, 0.0, spotName='CutContour', density=100)

    # Draw the image
    c.drawImage(ImageReader(image), cutline_offset, cutline_offset, img_width, img_height, mask='auto')

    # Set the spot color
    c.setStrokeColor(cut_contour_spot)

    # Draw the contour path
    c.setLineWidth(1)
    path = c.beginPath()

    # Start the path with a move to command
    path.moveTo(contour[0][0][0] + cutline_offset,
                (img_height + 2 * cutline_offset) - (contour[0][0][1] + cutline_offset))

    # Draw the contour path
    for point in contour[1:]:
        px, py = point[0]
        path.lineTo(px + cutline_offset,
                    (img_height + 2 * cutline_offset) - (py + cutline_offset))  # Adjust for coordinate system

    path.close()
    c.drawPath(path)

    # Save the PDF
    c.save()

    print(f"PDF with spot color cut contour created: {pdf_path}")


# Input image path
input_image_path = '2.png'

# Output PDF path
output_pdf_path = 'cut_contour_spot_color.pdf'

# Border size (pixels)
border_size = 12

# Corner radius (pixels)
corner_radius = 7

# Cutline offset (distance from border to cutline)
cutline_offset = 1

# Create image with rounded contour padding border
img_with_border = create_image_with_border(input_image_path, border_size, corner_radius)

# Create contour from image with border
contour = create_contour(img_with_border)

# Create the PDF with the spot color cut contour
create_pdf_with_spot_color(img_with_border, contour, output_pdf_path, cutline_offset)

print(f"PDF created: {os.path.abspath(output_pdf_path)}")

